# Unable to see Bindings on XAML page in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a project that is not showing the bindings on the XAML page.

> My RootObject

```
public class Notification
    {
        [JsonProperty("posts")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<Post>> posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image_url")]
        public Uri imageUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string time { get; set; }
    }
```

> My Service class(Code behind)

```
var notification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(apiContent);
                    List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
                    if (notification?.posts != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in notification.posts.Values)
                        {
                            posts.AddRange(item);
                        }
                    }
```

> My XAML file

```
<Label Text="{Binding title}" />
<Label Text="{Binding message}" />
```

When the parsing has completed on the XAML page it doesnt show the required title or message from the API.When i check the debugger it shows e a key/value pair that is for each post so i know its getting the data from the API.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you sure your collection contains data, and that each post has been populated?  Also, please post the complete XAML for your ListView

Comment: yes i am sure, when i check the debugger items are stored in a key/value pair for each post. I updated my XAML solution @Jason

Comment: Doesn't look like your setting `ItemsSource` for the list view, you to bind to collection to display items

Comment: `NotificationListView.ItemsSource = _schoolNotification;` isnt that setting the bindings to ListView?

Comment: try using a simple TextCell first to verify your bindings are working, then replace with a ViewCell

Comment: That's odd a `Service Class` shouldn't have direct access to the UI. Are you sure that service class is operating on the same instance of the page that's being displayed, it may have a separate instance. How does it get a ref to the page?

Comment: It gets a reference through the `ItemsSource` property @JSteward

Comment: Using a simple TextCell doesnt show anything either @Jason

Comment: @Anthony I meant how does the service get a reference to your page/listview

Comment: Oh i am doing it in the code behind for now, i am aware that you can use a View Model etc. For now its been done through the code behind @JSteward

Comment: Ok, can you post that code?

Comment: I updated my Service class solution @JSteward

Comment: turn IsGroupingEnabled off

Comment: I added the response returning from the JSON API, check post to see @Jason

Comment: I am seeing the data now with the TextCell, what i was trying to do is group the posts based on the date that is there on the JSON response from API. @Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn `IsGroupingEnabled` off.  The data in `ItemsSource` is not grouped, so you should not tell the `ListView` that it is.

To use grouping, review the [Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#Grouping) section in the ListView docs

Comment: Thanks i overlooked having that property in my XAML.